# java toString() returning this

Tags: java

In String `toString()` method returns `this` and when i pass it `System.out.println()` it prints the content of the `String`. It is confusing for me how is that happening. can comeone explain please.

`public String toString() {
    return this;
    }`

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

The `toString` method, defined on `Object` in Java is responsible for converting the object to a String representation. Since `String` is already a String, the `toString` method simply returns itself.

Comment: May also be helpful to know that the keyword `this` refers to the current object.

Answer (score 6):

> *and when i pass it System.out.println() it prints the content of the String*

In fact, when you pass a `String` to `System.out.println` **you don't go through `toString`** anyway. The `System.out` refers to a `PrintStream` object which has a method that accepts `String`s immediately:

> `public void println(String x)`
>
> Prints a String and then terminate the line.

---

The contract of [`toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) is to return a string representation of the object:

> `public String toString()`
>
> Returns a string representation of the object. **In general, the `toString` method returns a string that "textually represents" this object.** The result should be a concise but informative representation that is easy for a person to read. It is recommended that all subclasses override this method.

Since `String` happens to *be* a `String` it can return itself (`this`)!

Comment: And in fact, as your comment demonstrates, the contract for the toString method is very loose.  The implementation can vary wildly.  Many classes return just the class name and instance ID.  The String class returns the string value.  This means that the toString method is generally useful only for debugging.  One important exception to this is the StringBuffer's toString method.